# Streamlit not allowing access to SQL Database Connection

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy, streamlit

I am currently working on a natural language processing application with llamaindex, and I am trying to use StreamLit to make this available within my company; however, I cannot get it to work on StreamLit whatsoever. My code does work on my end if i do 'streamlit run app.py' in my terminal; however between github and the deployment, it keeps erroring out. For context purposes, it appears these lines of code are the most relevent (as it errors out at this line:
`metadata_obj.create_all(database_engine)` and suggests a problem with my engine.

```
import time, os, pinecone as p, streamlit as st, sqlalchemy as sa, pandas as pd, numpy as np, pyodbc
from sqlalchemy import Select, Column, VARCHAR, Table, create_engine, MetaData, inspect
from llama_index.llms import LlamaCPP
from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI
from llama_index import VectorStoreIndex, SQLDatabase
from llama_index.indices.struct_store import SQLTableRetrieverQueryEngine
from Secrets import OPENAI_API_KEY, PINECONE_API_KEY, SERVER, DATABASE, TABLES_CONN_STR

@st.cache_resource()
def getConnection(key):
    if key == 'tables':
        from Secrets import TABLES_CONN_STR
        tables_engine = create_engine(TABLES_CONN_STR)
        return tables_engine
    if key == 'data':
        db_conn_string = 'mssql+pyodbc://@' + SERVER + '/' + DATABASE + '?trusted_connection=yes&driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server'
        database_engine = create_engine(db_conn_string, pool_pre_ping=True)
        return database_engine 

def refreshSQLDatabase():
    database_engine = getConnection('data')
    #LOAD TABLE DEFINITIONS
    metadata_obj = MetaData()
    metadata_obj.create_all(database_engine)
    #ESTABLISH CONNECTION TO OUR DATABASE
    table_list = getTableNames()
    sql_database = SQLDatabase(database_engine, metadata=metadata_obj, include_tables=table_list, sample_rows_in_table_info=3)

    return sql_database
```

The streamlit error I am encountering is:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: This app has encountered an error. The original error message is redacted to prevent data leaks. Full error details have been recorded in the logs
```

the traceback I am getting for the error is as follows:

```
2023-11-01 18:01:31.811 Uncaught app exception

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/home/adminuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 145, in __init__

    self._dbapi_connection = engine.raw_connection()

  File "/home/adminuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3288, in raw_connection

    return self.pool.connect()

  File "/home/adminuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 452, in connect

    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)

  File "/home/adminuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 1267, in _checkout

    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)

  File "/home/adminuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 716, in checkout

    rec = pool._do_get()

  File "/home/adminuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 170, in _do_get

    self._dec_overflow()

  File "/home/adminuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 146, in __exit__

    raise exc_value.with_traceback(exc_tb)

  File "/home/adminuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 167, in _do_get

    return self._create_connection()

  File "/home/adminuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 393, in _create_connection

    return _ConnectionRecord(self)

  File "/home/adminuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 678, in __init__

    self.__connect()

  File "/home/adminuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 903, in __connect

    pool.logger.debug("Error on connect(): %s", e)

  File "/home/adminuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 146, in __exit__

    raise exc_value.with_traceback(exc_tb)

  File "/home/adminuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 898, in __connect

    self.dbapi_connection = connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)

  File "/home/adminuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/create.py", line 637, in connect

    return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)

  File "/home/adminuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 615, in connect

    return self.loaded_dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)

pyodbc.OperationalError: ('HYT00', '[HYT00] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:


Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/home/adminuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/streamlit/runtime/scriptrunner/script_runner.py", line 541, in _run_script

    exec(code, module.__dict__)

  File "/mount/src/cmac_ai_bot/app.py", line 102, in <module>

    sql_database = refreshSQLDatabase()

  File "/mount/src/cmac_ai_bot/app.py", line 38, in refreshSQLDatabase

    metadata_obj.create_all(database_engine)

  File "/home/adminuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py", line 5813, in create_all

    bind._run_ddl_visitor(

  File "/home/adminuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3238, in _run_ddl_visitor

    with self.begin() as conn:

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/contextlib.py", line 119, in __enter__

    return next(self.gen)

  File "/home/adminuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3228, in begin

    with self.connect() as conn:

  File "/home/adminuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3264, in connect

    return self._connection_cls(self)

  File "/home/adminuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 147, in __init__

    Connection._handle_dbapi_exception_noconnection(

  File "/home/adminuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2426, in _handle_dbapi_exception_noconnection

    raise sqlalchemy_exception.with_traceback(exc_info[2]) from e

  File "/home/adminuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 145, in __init__

    self._dbapi_connection = engine.raw_connection()

  File "/home/adminuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3288, in raw_connection

    return self.pool.connect()

  File "/home/adminuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 452, in connect

    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)

  File "/home/adminuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 1267, in _checkout

    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)

  File "/home/adminuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 716, in checkout

    rec = pool._do_get()

  File "/home/adminuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 170, in _do_get

    self._dec_overflow()

  File "/home/adminuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 146, in __exit__

    raise exc_value.with_traceback(exc_tb)

  File "/home/adminuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 167, in _do_get

    return self._create_connection()

  File "/home/adminuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 393, in _create_connection

    return _ConnectionRecord(self)

  File "/home/adminuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 678, in __init__

    self.__connect()

  File "/home/adminuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 903, in __connect

    pool.logger.debug("Error on connect(): %s", e)

  File "/home/adminuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 146, in __exit__

    raise exc_value.with_traceback(exc_tb)

  File "/home/adminuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 898, in __connect

    self.dbapi_connection = connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)

  File "/home/adminuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/create.py", line 637, in connect

    return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)

  File "/home/adminuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 615, in connect

    return self.loaded_dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)

sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pyodbc.OperationalError) ('HYT00', '[HYT00] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/e3q8)
```

Comment: I presume you've done `print(db_conn_string)` to actually look at the connection string once in production....?

Comment: I have,  I'm pretty sure the connection string isn't the problem, as it works without streamlit

Comment: Well, it is a problem with that string in one way or another. Either the string is now pointing to a resource that doesn't exist in the deployment env or your database is down. You say it "works without streamlit" but then also say "however between github and the deployment, it keeps erroring out" - so it's not running in the same relative location, you're implying.

Comment: `trusted_connection=yes`? When you execute this yourself it's using your Windows/Kerberos process token to authenticate against the SQL Server instance. How have you managed to setup Kerberos authentication so that it can work from Streamlit as well? Have you tried to make it work using username-password-based SQL Login authentication?